# DidDeselect cells off screen

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ipados

I am trying to show the selected cell in my `UICollectionView` by changing its border and shadow color. my issue is that my `DidDeselect` function causes a crash if I select a cell then scroll the selected cell of screen and select another cell, I understand that is because my `DidDeselect` is trying to deselect a cell that has been reused so my question is:

How do I remove the border from a cell that is no longer visible once it has scrolled off the screen

My `DidSelect`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PresentationCell
    cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cell.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
}
```

My `DidDeSelect`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cellItem = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PresentationCell
    cellItem.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cellItem.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cellItem.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
 }
```

It crashes on this line:

```
let cellItem = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PresentationCell
```

Error is : `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Which I understand is because the cell I selected first is no longer displayed because I've scrolled it out of view and then selected a cell at the bottom of the `collectionView`

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a correct behavior. When you use the `dequeueReusableCell` cell are reused and memory gets allocated to visible cells only. So, if you try to pull a cell which is already deallocated then it will gives you `nil`.

In your case, you need to have some custom implementation where you can hold the selection and apply the logic.

Following is the working code...

**Declare the variable at top**

```
var mySelection = -1
```

**Use this code block for rest of logic**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    if mySelection == indexPath.row {
      applySelection(cell: cell, index: indexPath.row)
    } else {
      removeSelection(cell: cell, index: indexPath.row)
    }
    return cell
 }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
 {
    mySelection = indexPath.row
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) 
    {
      applySelection(cell: cell, index: indexPath.row)
    }
 }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
 didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
 {
    if let cellItem = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) 
    {
      removeSelection(cell: cellItem, index: indexPath.row)
    }
 }

func applySelection(cell: UICollectionViewCell, index: Int) {
      cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
      cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
      cell.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
 }

func removeSelection(cell: UICollectionViewCell, index: Int) {
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
    cell.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
 }
```

Comment: If you want to have multiple selections, then use array to hold selection instate of `mySelection` variable. It will change your comparison condition in `cellForItemAt` method.

Answer (score 0):

Elevate you not doing proper way to achieve your requirements

below i suggest to way achieving your requirement.

put your border colour and width in your cell method

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
      "id_PresentationCell", for: indexPath) as! PresentationCell
   if arrYourData[IndexPath.row].isSelected == true {
        cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
  }
        
}
```

**When tap on didSelected Make isSelected true on tap like beolow :**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.arrYourData[IndexPath.row].isSelected = !self.arrYourData[IndexPath.row].isSelected 

**Reload your collection here**
     }
```